# How to use an ArrayAdapter to return and show a ListView

Tags: android

I am writing code for an mp3 player I am trying to create. I am only at the start of the project and want to be able to read and show all of the mp3 files that is on my sd card. I don't want to use the direct path method. Now this code I have written gathers all of the mp3 files for me but the only problem is that it does not view them on screen for me. The app shows a blank screen, but doesn't crash.

I got help and advice off of a tutor and I was told to use an ArrayAdapter to view the results but I can't find any help to show it. If anyone could please help that would be great.

Here is my code in the onCreate method;

```
ListView list;
Cursor cursor;
int columnIndex;
int count;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //A array is created that display the 3 fields
    String[] displayMusic = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};
    //the cursor displays all of the audio in the sd card, just to limit to .mp3 files now
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, displayMusic, null, null, null);

    //this is the loop that gather all of the .mp3 files
    int pos = 1;
    ArrayList<String> listOfMp3s = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        if(cursor.getString(pos).endsWith("mp3"))
        {
            listOfMp3s.add(cursor.getString(pos));
        }
    }


    String[] displayFields = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int[] displayViews = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
    //setListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, displayFields, displayViews);
    ArrayAdapter<String> musicAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_songs, listOfMp3s);
    //list.setAdapter(listOfMp3s);
 }
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look a the simple and straight forward tutorial [How to create a ListView using ArrayAdapter in Android](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/how-to-create-a-listview-using-arrayadapter-in-android/).

You need to generate a String array and attach the array to an Array adapter

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, YourStringArray);
```

and then plug this adapter to your ListView

```
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Or you could create your own custom adapter by extending `ArrayAdapter<YourItem>` and attaching `YourItem` array to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` to populate a `ListView` from your objects the way you want.

The advantage of this technic is that you gain a Views recycle mechanism that will recycle the `Views` inside you `ListView` in order to spend less memory.

**In Short** you would have to:

**1.** Create  an object that represents your data for a single row.

**2.** Create an `ArrayList` of those objects.

**3.** Create a layout that contains a ListView or add a ListView to you main layout using code.

**4.** Create a layout of a single row.

**5.** Create a `ViewHolder` that will represent the visual aspect of you data row from the stand point of `Views`.

**6.** Create a custom `ArrayAdapter` that will populate the rows according to you needs, in it you will override the `getView` method to specify exactly what the row data would be.

**7.** Finally assign this `ArrayAdapter` to your `ListView` in `onCreate`.

You can get an idea of how to implement this by reading this blog post I wrote:

[Create a Custom ArrayAdapter](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=495)